# No images displayed when website called from self written webserver how to solve this

Tags: java, html, post, httpserver

I check requests from the client and responses from the server with Charles. It sends the files (like CSS or js) fine, but doesn't with images: though the status is "200 OK" the transfer-encoding is chunked ... I have no idea what that means!? Does anybody know?

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/guestBook", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null);
    server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("/Users/rahul.joshi/Flower-Catalog/src/main/java/htmlpages/index.html");
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
        try (OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody()) {
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), os);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the file you are trying to send exists and you have the correct permissions on it?